# what is difference between @ and @:?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

tell me what is difference between `@ and @: ?`

when one use this `sign @: ?`

i got one

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.radios as string[])
  {
    @:<input type='radio' name='radiovalue' value='@item' /> @item <br />
  }
```

in the above code @ sign used like `@: foreach` then again why people give `@: sign` before starting `html` code like below one

```
@:<input type='radio' name='radiovalue' value='@item' /> @item <br />
```

when one should use `@: sign ?`

please discuss with sample code to better understand the usage. thanks

Comment: Some [informations](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use `@:` to explicitly tell razor to switch to text mode. Razor intelligent enough to automatically switch between code and text. But for any reason it could not you could use `@:` to help razor. Consider this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Name)@: : @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
}
```

in this example if you remove `@:` from middle of statement razor thinks we use `:` in C# code but actually we want to use `:` in html not C#.